# Using a variable to specify a column name within `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to use a variable to specify the name of a column when operating on it.

To give an example I can might have a data.table called `Set1` in which I want to change the class of column `x` to numeric. I might do

```
Set1New=transform(Set1,x=as.numeric(x))
```

This will work, but now I don't want to hard code the column name, but rather use a variable, lets's call it `Y` (which has previously been defined as `Y="x"`.

How do I tell R to use the content of the variable instead of looking for a column `Y` when I use

```
Set1New=transform(Set1,Y=as.numeric(Y))
```

I know that e.g. `setkey` and `setkeyv` exist, where `setkeyv` solves this issue. Is there a similar solution for transform? **Or, what I would like better, is there a general solution to use the content of the variable instead of the variable name?**

Comment: If it is a data.table, then `Set1[, x:=as.numeric(x)]`

Comment: You probably looking for `Set1[, (Y) := as.numeric(get(Y))]`. In general, if you already using `data.table`, operation such as `Set1New=transform(..` takes all the point of using it in the first place. You should read some `data.table` documentation about NSE and assignment by reference. More specifically look [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) and [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/tree/master/vignettes)

Comment: Or you could use `eval` `Set1[,(Y) := as.numeric(eval(as.name(Y)))]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks! I see your point of using these kind of operations on data.tables. The problem is that I am quite new to R (and data.table) so I am still trying to figure out the correct (and most efficient) syntax for my operations

Comment: That's fine, thus I recommend you'll take some time on reading the vignettes

Comment: @DavidArenburg I will certainly do that!

Comment: Also take a look [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Data**:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(col1=letters[1:2], x=c('1','2'))
```

One solution is to use `quote` and the `eval` in your `data.table`:

```
y = quote(x)
dt[,eval(y):=as.numeric(eval(y))]

#> is.numeric(dt$x)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found